# Create 100 strings in one array (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create an array with 100 strings which are made like this:

```
sequence = []


for i in range(0, 16):
    sequence.append(np.random.choice(nucleotides, 1, p = pfmNew[:,i]))

sequence=[val for sublist in sequence for val in sublist]  
sequence = "".join(sequence)

print(sequence)
```

This is the output that I get:

```
TCGTTCACAGTGACAT
```

Now I want to do this 100 times and have them in one array like this:

```
['TCGTTCACAGTGACAT', 'next string', ...]
```

Comment: Can you post some code for what you have tried, and any errors you're getting?

Comment: add an outter loop?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, and the code you provided as a skeleton can be improved by sampling 16 nucleotides at a time by setting the `size` argument in `np.random.choice` to 16. Then, you can just loop through that 100 times.

```
nucleotides = list('ACGT')

sequence = []

for _ in range(100):
    sequence.append(''.join(np.random.choice(nucleotides, 16, p = pfmNew[:,i])))

# Or you can replace the loop by a list comprehension:
# sequence = [''.join(np.random.choice(nucleotides, 16, p = pfmNew[:,i])) for _ in range(100)]

# Take a look at the first 10:
sequence[:10]

['TTCACTACCCGCAAAC', 'CTCCTGATACAGATCG', 'CTTGACGATGCTCCGA', 'ATGACCAATGAAGCCG', 'TTGCCGACGTCGATTG', 'ATATTCTTGCGCAGGT', 'CTTAGCCCATCACCCC', 'GGGTTTCCGCCTCGTA', 'ACGTCAAGTGCAGTGC', 'GGTAGATCCGAAACGC']
```